# Calling external program from R with multiple commands in system

Tags: r, shell, command-line, external-process

I am new to programming and mainly I am able to do some scripts within R, but for my work I need to call an external program. For this program to work on the ubuntu's terminal I have to first use setenv and then execute the program. Googling I've found the system () and Sys.setenv() functions, but unfortunately I can make it function.

This is the code that does work in the ubuntu terminal:

```
$ export PATH=/home/meme/bin:$PATH
$ mast "/home/meme/meme.txt" "/home/meme/seqs.txt" -o "/home/meme/output" -comp
```

Where the first two arguments are input files, the -o argument is the output directory and the -comp is another parameter for the program to run.

The reason that I need to do it in R despite it already works in the terminal is because I need to run the program 1000 times with 1000 different files so I want to make a for loop where the input name changes in every loop and then analyze every output in R.

I have already tried to use:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="/home/meme/bin"); system(mast "/home/meme/meme.txt" "/home/meme/seqs.txt" -o "/home/meme/output" -comp )
```

and

```
system(Sys.setenv(PATH="/home/meme/bin") && mast "/home/meme/meme.txt" "/home/meme/seqs.txt" -o "/home/meme/output" -comp )
```

but always received:

```
Error: unexpected constant string in "system(mast "/home/meme/meme.txt""
```

or

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "system(Sys.setenv(PATH="/home/meme/bin") && mast "/home/meme/meme.txt""
```

At this point I have run out of ideas to make this work. If this has already been answered, then my googling have just been poor and I would appreciate any links to its response.

Thank you very much for your time.

Carlos

Additional details:

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bits version, RStudio version 0.97.551, R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing" Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).
The program I use (MAST) finds a sequence pattern in a list of letters and is part of the MEME SUIT version 4.9.1 found in http://meme.nbcr.net/meme/doc/meme-install.html and run through command line. The command-line usage for mast is:

```
mast    <motif file> <sequence file> [options]
```

Answer (score 13):

Construct the string you want to execute with `paste` and feed that to `system`:

```
for(i in 1:10){
cmd=paste("export FOO=",i," ; echo \"$FOO\" ",sep='')
system(cmd)
}
```

Note the use of `sep=''` to stop `paste` putting spaces in, and back-quoting quote marks in the string to preserve them.

Test before running by using `print(cmd)` instead of `system(cmd)` to make sure you are getting the right command built. Maybe do:

```
if(TESTING){print(cmd)}else{system(cmd)}
```

and set `TESTING=TRUE` or `FALSE` in R before running.

If you are going to be running more than one shell command per `system` call, it might be better to put them all in one shell script file and call that instead, passing parameters from R. Something like:

```
cmd = paste("/home/me/bin/dojob.sh ",i,i+1)
system(cmd)
```

and then `dojob.sh` is a shell script that parses the args. You'll need to learn a bit more shell scripting.