# How can I certify a file is exactly the same?

Tags: r, hashcode

Is there a package or function that can be applied to a whole and heavy data object to get back a measure of changes in the file? Something based on hash keys would be great, so I can keep track on a shared file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[digest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digest/) package (`digest` function) lets you create hash functions for R objects (possible ones: "md5", "sha1", "crc32", "sha256", "sha512", "xxhash32", "xxhash64"). You can also run external programs from R (e.g. `md5sum` on linux) with `system` commend (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966209/calling-external-program-from-r-with-multiple-commands-in-system)).